# all cases of Doubly linked list Insertion at a given position is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, logic

I have created a Doubly linked list Insertion at a given position program using JavaScript. It is supposed to append at the beginning, middle, and end of the node.

Here is the problem: all test cases are not working fine, like for this input:

```
2 4 5
2 6
```

My output is `2 6 4 5` and the expected output is `2 4 5 6`.

Could you please rectify my mistake and modify that so all the edge cases will work fine here? `head`, `pos`, and `data` are the starting pointers. `pos` means in which position you want to enter the new node, and `data` is new data. The code is given below.

#### Example 1

Input:

- LinkedList: `2<->4<->5`
- `p = 2`, `x = 6`

Output:

- `2 4 5 6`

Explanation:

`p = 2`, and `x = 6`. So, 6 is inserted after `p`, i.e, at position 3.

#### Example 2

Input:

- LinkedList: `1<->2<->3<->4`
- `p = 0`, `x = 44`

Output:

- `1 44 2 3 4`

Explanation:

`p = 0`, and `x = 44` . So, 44 is inserted after `p`, i.e, at position 1.

```
class Solution {
    addNode(head, pos, data) {
        const newHead = { data: data, prev: null, next: null }; 

        if (head === null) {
            return newHead; 
        }
        let temp = head;
        for (let i = 1; i < pos - 1 && temp.next !== null; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (pos > 1 && temp === null) {
            return head;
        }

        newHead.next = temp.next;
        if (temp.next !== null) {
            temp.next.prev = newHead;
        }

        temp.next = newHead;
        newHead.prev = temp;

        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the insert/calling part to the question.

Comment: this is already wrapped in a class and input added

Comment: btw, why is not `p = 0` before the first node? how can you add later a node at start?

Comment: this is a function which will handle start middle and last insertion

Comment: You say it can handle start... so how can you insert a value at the start? For instance, how can you turn 1→2→3 into 0→1→2→3 ?? What should be the value of `p` to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- The `for` loop does not make enough iterations to meet the definition of `pos`. For instance, if `pos` is 1, then the loop should make one iteration so that `temp` references the second node (at index 1).
- The `if` statement after the loop checks the value of `pos` as if it had changed in the loop, but obviously it didn't. Moreover, this means that if `pos` is less than 2, and `temp` happens to be `null`, you'll run into an error when accessing `temp.next`. This `if` condition should not check the value of `pos`.
- There is no provision for inserting a node *in front* of the list so that it becomes the first node. With the interpretation of `pos` you would have to pass a value of -1 to insert a new node in front of the list, but your code has no provision for this case.
- There is an inconsistency in behaviour when the list is empty and when it is not. When it is empty, your code does not validate the `pos` argument, but when the list is not empty, and the value for `pos` is too great, your function does not (intend to) append the new node. This is not consistent. You should also make this check when the list is empty, i.e. when you're inserting the very first node. Given the above observations, `pos` should have the value -1 when you want to insert the first node.

Here is the code with corrections for the above listed points:

```
    addNode(head, pos, data) {
        const newHead = { data: data, prev: null, next: null }; 

        if (pos == -1) { // Insert at start
            newHead.next = head;
            if (head) {
                head.prev = newHead;
            }
            return newHead;
        }
        
        if (!head) { // Invalid value for pos argument
            return head; 
        }
        
        let temp = head;
        // Number of iterations corrected
        for (let i = 0; i < pos && temp.next; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        // Check only temp
        if (!temp) { // Invalid value for pos argument
            return head;
        }

        newHead.next = temp.next;
        if (temp.next) {
            temp.next.prev = newHead;
        }

        temp.next = newHead;
        newHead.prev = temp;

        return head;
    }
```

Final remark: this is an uncommon way of specifying `pos`. It would make more sense if `pos` reflected the index that the new node would have once it was inserted in the list. So then `pos` should be one more than your specifications currently specify.